# Removing a static UIView from a UITableView with Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a storyboard I'm maintaining that is a `UITableViewController`.

The `UITableView` is set to use Dynamic Prototypes and has 2 cells.

Above those two cells is a `UIView` inserted within the table view. That view contains a `UIButton` and another custom `UIView`. Both have constraints. The effect is that we have a table view with a button above it.

Now, in certain conditions, we want to remove that button and have the rest of the table view move up in the UI. I can remove that button -- by itself or by removing that parent UIView, but I cannot seem to to get the table to change the position of the prototype cells.

To hopefully make it clear, my document outline looks like this:

- Table View

  - View (buttonContainerView mentioned below)

    - UIButton
    - View (child view mentioned below)
    - Constraints
  - Prototype Cell 1
  - Prototype Cell 2

I have tried several different approaches to remove the button. After reading that removing it from the superview will remove constraints as well, that's the approach I currently have in place.

```
[self.buttonContainerView removeFromSuperview];
```

I've tried removing the button, the child view, and the container view. I've also tried explicitly removing the constraints then removing the views. None of these seemed to work.

I've also tried the above with calls to setNeedsLayout and setNeedsUpdateConstraints on the table view, as well as setNeedsDisplay on the view.

I've also tried setting the row height to 0 for that first view, but it turns out it's not a `UITableViewCell`, so that doesn't work, either.

Of course, if I delete that container view from the storyboard, the prototype cells do appear in the UI exactly where they should.

Can you sense the flailing about?

What else could I be missing here to remove that top view effectively?

Comment: After a day thinking about it I'm leaning towards converting that child UIView (buttonContainerView) to a prototype cell and handling the hide status in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath + tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't realize is that the setup I have is a UITableView with a table header. To remove it and fix the spacing problem I was having I just needed to set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil` in `viewWillAppear:`.